# Getting argument data's type Tensor[3,850,850] is incompatible with the type Tensor[3,370,1224] of the passed Variable on cntk

Tags: cntk

I am getting argument data's type Tensor[3,850,850] is incompatible with the type Tensor[3,370,1224] of the passed Variable error when running cntk's Fast RCNN sample code.

Sometime the number in Tensor[] changes...without any modification on config files
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was crash between network model image size and new trainning image configuration After I erase model I train earlier. It worked!

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved. On Stack Overflow, we do that by writing an answer in an answer box below, and then clicking the tick mark. Would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

It was crash between network model image size and new trainning image configuration After I erase model I train earlier. It worked!